# Webpack plugin to statically analyze the usage of an exported function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, optimization, static-analysis

To start, please be aware that I am setting up this hypothetical problem *intentionally*, because it's a real world problem which I am faced with solving, and am not sure it's even possible.

Let's say I have a JavaScript package, called `road-fetcher`, with an exported function called `find`, which I can pass a lat/lng coordinate into, and get back the nearest road to that point.

So:

```
import { find } from 'road-fetcher'

find(36.585940, -95.304241) // output: 'US Route 66'
```

Let's suppose that a user consuming my `road-fetcher` app ends up using this `find` function 200-300x in their web app (all in predictable, non `Math.random` ways).

Internally, my `road-fetcher` package is making network requests to my external API. That works fine, but if we keep doing this at runtime, we incur bandwidth and latency costs (whether in browser or server) on each client, that we needn't necessarily. Moreover, maybe all 200 calls are on the same page. Instead, it'd be ideal to generate initial values at *build time*, and perhaps set some long TTL to revalidate values later on.

It's commonplace to process JavaScript with Webpack, and I'm wondering if it would be possible to statically analyse a user's usage of the `find` function to find all the permutations.

Ideally I'd want to compile a total list of function calls with their args and then make a network request based on this, during the build step, but even being able to compile a list of all function call args and store that somewhere in the filesystem (not sure, within `node_modules`, or cwd), to facilitate a single cache-warm step would be sufficient as well.

Having an initial look at the Webpack docs, it seems like [`evaluateCallExpressionMember`](https://webpack.js.org/api/parser/#evaluatecallexpressionmember) *may* be a starting point, but I'm pretty out of my depth here.

I appreciate this is a contrived example, but it does represent a very real problem which I am trying to simplify here to clearly isolate the issue at hand.

Comment: Great idea, but it is only partially achievable. When someone calls your function with ```find(36.585940, -95.304241)``` it's more less simple. But what if it calls it with find(x, y), where x and y calculated on runtime based on user input?  If this is not the case, you might check this package, they are doing something similar for translations: https://github.com/akameco/extract-react-intl-messages

Comment: @Drag13 That's not a problem, as truly dynamic calls would just fall back to "normal" fetching behaviour. The hope is to catch the majority of cases via static analysis.

Comment: This is a fascinating problem and I hope you get a truly usable answer. In the meantime, have you considered building in a caching mechanism into your api, or even wrapping the api with a caching service in the interim? It offloads the problem from JS static analysis and into a more well documented realm that should offer similar performance enhancements.

Comment: @JamesTomasino Yes, we'd have multiple layers of caching: (1) in-memory at API level, (2) CDN level, (3) in-memory at client level. I'm also really hoping someone comes along and surprises us – a solution to this problem could optimise a lot of pre-existing modules/packages.

Comment: Are you using plain JS, or would be using [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org) also an option? I'm asking since typescript has a really need transformer API which allows you to statically analize your code and transform it (Like evaluating find(x, y) even at compile/transpile time).

Comment: @WolverinDEV Yes, TypeScript is an option, but ideally this package would be available to all JS consumers. Can you link to that TS transformer API?

Answer (score 5):

I managed to write a webpack plugin that accepts a function name, and a callback that will be called with the arguments that were passed to the original function.

> Here is the [repo](https://github.com/jackyef/function-call-webpack-plugin) if you just want to jump into the code

It works, with some limitations:

1. It only works with ES modules
2. It does not work if a named import is renamed (e. g.: `import { log as logg } from './something'`
3. It does not work if the arguments passed to the function are variables

#### Results

This is my source code:

```
import { log } from './helpers/log';

// these will be logged
log(1);
log(2, 3);
log(2, "foo");
log(2, "foo", 4, "bar");
log(2, "foo", 4, "bar", [1, 2, "asd"]);
log(2, "foo", 4, "bar", [1, 2, "asd"], { foo: "bar" }, [
  { a: "asd", b: 123, c: [] },
]);

// this one will not be logged because it's using a variable
const a = [1,2,3];
log(a);

// this one will also not be logged because it's not using `log` exactly
console.log('asd');
```

This is the webpack config:

```
const FunctionCallPlugin = require('./webpack-plugins/FunctionCall');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [ new FunctionCallPlugin({ functionName: 'log', callback: ({ arguments: args }) => {
    console.log('`log` function was found and called with the arguments:', args);
    // you can do whatever here, make a http request, write to db, etc
  }})],
}
```

This is the terminal outputs when running webpack:

```
➜  webpack-plugin-function-invoke git:(master) ✗ yarn webpack
yarn run v1.16.0
warning ..\package.json: No license field
$ D:\Projects\webpack-plugin-function-invoke\node_modules\.bin\webpack
`log` function was found and called with the arguments: [ 1 ]
`log` function was found and called with the arguments: [ 2, 3 ]
`log` function was found and called with the arguments: [ 2, 'foo' ]
`log` function was found and called with the arguments: [ 2, 'foo', 4, 'bar' ]
`log` function was found and called with the arguments: [ 2, 'foo', 4, 'bar', [ 1, 2, 'asd' ] ]
`log` function was found and called with the arguments: [
  2,
  'foo',
  4,
  { foo: 'bar' },
  [ { a: 'asd', b: 123, c: [] } ]
]
```

#### How the plugin works

1. It loops through all webpack chunks, and all modules inside of each chunks to see if they have any dependencies with the specified name. For example, if you are looking for `log`, it will find any modules that either does `import { log } from './somewhere'` or `import log from './somewhere'`
2. For every modules that have the specified dependencies, it collect all the file paths to the original source code by looking at its `fileDependencies`
3. Each of the files' source code are read as string using `fs` module
4. The source code are parsed into an AST using babel parser
5. The AST is traversed and we look into all `CallExpression` that uses the same specified function name
6. We collect all the arguments used in the function call
7. We run the specified callback, while passing the collected arguments

That's it! It is probably not that performant, but hey it works :)

I have put this in a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/jackyef/function-call-webpack-plugin) if you are interested in the code. I know that this is not the complete answer to your question, but hopefully it helps!